# Why isn't my Eq constraint based on an overloaded function correctly inferred?

Tags: javascript, typescript, polymorphism, overloading, adhoc-polymorphism

This is a simple attempt to use an overloaded function as an equality constraint for a generic higher order function:

```
function eq(x: boolean, y: boolean): boolean;
function eq(x: number, y: number): boolean;
function eq(x: string, y: string): boolean;

function eq(x: any, y: any) { return x === y };

const arrEq = <A>(eq: (x: A, y: A) => boolean) => (xs: A[]) => (ys: A[]) => {
    const go = (b: boolean, i: number): boolean =>
        b === false ? false
            : i === xs.length ? true
                : go(eq(xs[i], ys[i]), i + 1);

    return go(true, 0)
};

arrEq(eq) ([1, 2, 3]) ([1, 2, 3]); // A
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=16&pc=35#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAUwI4AoAeAuRAjOOAG2QEMwAaRAT1wOLLAEo7CTyBuAWAChRJYCFBhyIwIALZ5kAJyq0xk6TJb42jbn3DR4SNFlwBnKDJhgA5vKMmz51fXZhNvfjqH7R5alcRemiAG9EGWQoEBkkTEQAXliaRABfZx4IBGNfGRkAUVQYxAAeAEEAPnQ0XANEQp9C-2jitQZyOoasQ1xCgG0AXRbEdGp2qp6+gN5ECcRUsHTzODz0PFYmykQYXHEpWXt1chji8cmjvBi44FIiQ2REAH5Ec8vkQ6OXxFwYU+jETEMAOhILFAABa3RAmEBPHivaGTXBzMoiQydGDdeRIlFMKgfADUiAAjExkkcQmEIoh4eDkFQAAxMXhJXi8UiZHII-zoTp4qgAJioAGZev1OTz+b0OEA)

In line `A` the type variable `A` is inferred as `string`, which seems quite arbitrarily. How can I fix this?

Comment: Design limitation, see [microsoft/TypeScript#35641](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/35641), [microsoft/TypeScript#30369](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30369).

Comment: You'd be better off using a generic instead of overloads, maybe like [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAUwI4B4AqA+AFADwC5FNEAyRXAZygCcYwBzRAH0TBAFsAjZW1xNzhwANsgCGYAJQAaRAE9imKcSGiJSAN4BYAFCIDiWsighaSfIgC8NhXoC+Abj16ICGonG1aAUVTXEdABBPDRiAmIguUVEIKlrbEFhMUl4q0SCKkiAbQBdNIz5LNi8gsQdfUM3MA9GOADcblVkjTkYYg4ePhUk9UkEvUMhwWtbYHERKmREAH5EccnkQeGV4hhRq0R8KgA6MSYoAAtZxDoQJcqVq8RiOtw0TOyYXOiqJ-y2xABqRABGKWcumWBmMpnMiDuZ2QcgADFIHIC9F5fKh7qgpLhsr85AAmOQAZnymOxiDxiEJUiAA).  I can write up this as an answer if you want

Comment: @jcalz No, thank you. This example is part of a post to explain the difference between ad-hoc polymorphism by name overloading and by type classes. Thanks for the github references. I read somewhere that the polymorphism gained by function overloading is called ad-hoc, because it is not part of the actual type system. Maybe this is the reason why TS cannot infer types and resolve overloaded names at the same time.